# how to connect 3 dell non-thunderbolt displays to a 2014 15" macbook pro

Tags: display, thunderbolt, displayport

so i have three 'standard' 24" Dell displays (1920x1280 resolution). they have hdmi, display port (normal) and vga. i would like to connect all three of them to my new macbook pro 15".

i think i could get two mini displayport to (full) displayport cables, and connect two of the monitors this way; and the third via hdmi.

however, i would also like to make use of a gigE ethernet card. i suppose i could get a usb<->ethernet adapter.

but, i would very much like to minimize cabling as much as possible.

is there a docking solution out there that can, say, enable one thunderbolt connection to all three Dell monitors? (and provide a gigE ethernet). The belkin one [Belkin Thunderbolt 2 Express HD Dock](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NAWCU7G) appears to only allow two displays.

Comment: i saw the adaprer on amazon and says it does not support MAC OS. if it really works, I suppose i can connect the adapter to the belkin station's thunderbolt.

Answer (score 1):

There's a product by 'StarTech.com' that can do this as described, their "Mini DisplayPort 1.2 to Triple Head DisplayPort Multi Monitor MST Hub". You will need 3x miniDP to DP cables for your Dell monitors.

You will then need to pick-up a USB 3.0 network adapter which will support Full Duplex 2Gbps to complete your set-up as described.

Unfortunately if you want to cut down on cabling you will need to spend some cash on getting Thunderbolt enabled monitors, which are nice, but overpriced.

Comment: does the macbookpro's (i have a an 11,3) / yosemite support daisy chaining? (ie MST?)